# Remove duplicates from csv based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

The task is basically this:

I am given the following csv file with lots of duplicate email addresses

```
Display Name,First Name,Last Name,Phone Number,Email Address,Login Date,Registration Date
John,John,Doe,99999999,johndoe@yahoo.com,4/20/2015 21:56,4/20/2015 21:56
John,John,DOE,99999999,johndoe@yahoo.com,3/31/2015 14:05,3/31/2015 14:05
```

I need to remove duplicates based on email address with the following conditions:

1. The row with the latest login date must be selected.
2. The oldest registration date among the rows must be used.

I used Python/pandas to do this.

How do I optimize the for loop in this pandas script using groupby? I tried hard but I'm still banging my head against it.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('pra.csv')

# first sort the data by Login Date since we always need the latest Login date first
# we're making a copy so as to keep the original data intact, while still being able to sort by datetime
df['Login Date Copy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Login Date'])
df['Registration Date Copy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Registration Date'])

# this way latest login date appears first for each duplicate pair
df = df.sort_values(by='Login Date Copy', ascending=False)

output_df = pd.DataFrame()

# get rows for each email address and replace registration date with the oldest one
# this can probably be optimized using groupby
for email in df['Email Address'].unique():
    subdf = df.loc[df['Email Address'] == email]
    oldest_date = subdf['Registration Date Copy'].min()

    # get corresponding registration date for a particular registration date copy
    oldest_reg_date = df[df['Registration Date Copy'] == oldest_date]['Registration Date'].values[0]

    subdf['Registration Date'] = oldest_reg_date
    output_df = output_df.append(subdf)

# drop working columns
output_df.drop(['Login Date Copy', 'Registration Date Copy'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# finally, get only the first of the duplicates and output the result
output_df = output_df.drop_duplicates(subset='Email Address', keep='first')
output_df.to_csv('~/output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` is pretty much the same as what you are doing using the first line in your `for` loop. So you can change:

> ```
> for email in df['Email Address'].unique():
>     subdf = df.loc[df['Email Address'] == email]
>     ...
> ```

by

```
for email, subdf in df.groupby('Email Address'):
    ...
```

---

Now, to improve this loop:

- `subdf['Registration Date Copy'].min()` is not what you want since it gives you the value and you are interested by its index (as you are filtering and getting `values[0]` on the next line). Use `argmin()` instead to get the index so you can directly get the desired value with `subdf['Registration Date'][<variable_name_you_stored_argmin_into>]`
- You can modify a specific cell of a DataFrame using `df.set_value(index, column, value)`, no need to use an intermediate dataframe here. Since you will drop everything but the firsts elements of each group, you can change only the ones at `subdf.index[0]`.

This yield:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pra.csv')

# Sort the data by Login Date since we always need the latest
# Login date first. We're making a copy so as to keep the
# original data intact, while still being able to sort by datetime
df['Login Date Copy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Login Date'])
df['Registration Date Copy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Registration Date'])
df.sort_values(by='Login Date Copy', ascending=False, inplace=True)

# Change the registration date of the first duplicate to the oldest one
for email, group in df.groupby('Email Address'):
    oldest_index = group['Registration Date Copy'].argmin()
    oldest_registration = group['Registration Date'][oldest_index]
    df.set_value(group.index[0], 'Registration Date', oldest_registration)

# Drop working columns
df.drop(['Login Date Copy', 'Registration Date Copy'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Finally, get only the first of the duplicates and output the result
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Email Address', keep='first', inplace=True)
df.to_csv('~/output.csv', index=False)
```

I also changed a bit the formating of the comments and used `inplace=True` instead of `df = df.whatever()`.

---

Finally, you may consider wrapping that in a function so you can easily change the values of the input/output parameters:

```
import pandas as pd


def main(input_csv, output_csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_csv)

    # Sort the data by Login Date since we always need the latest
    # Login date first. We're making a copy so as to keep the
    # original data intact, while still being able to sort by datetime
    df['Login Date Copy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Login Date'])
    df['Registration Date Copy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Registration Date'])
    df.sort_values(by='Login Date Copy', ascending=False, inplace=True)

    # Change the registration date of the first duplicate to the oldest one
    for email, group in df.groupby('Email Address'):
        oldest_index = group['Registration Date Copy'].argmin()
        oldest_registration = group['Registration Date'][oldest_index]
        df.set_value(group.index[0], 'Registration Date', oldest_registration)

    # Drop working columns
    df.drop(['Login Date Copy', 'Registration Date Copy'], axis=1, inplace=True)

    # Finally, get only the first of the duplicates and output the result
    df.drop_duplicates(subset='Email Address', keep='first', inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(output_csv, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('pra.csv', '~/output.csv')
```